# Github workflow succeeded, gh-page is updated but I can't see my site

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages-deploy-action

I want to deploy my site with Github Action.

pic 1- From the start, Github does not show the link where my site will be deployed.

pic 2- I see the workflow that was successful, the gh-page branch  is updated but I don't see the link to my site.

what is the problem ?

[image: pic 2]

[image]

Comment: I think you want the source to be `Deploy from a branch`. At least, that's how my github pages are setup, and that's what the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart) says to do.

Comment: Your GitHub Actions workflow will update the `gh-pages` branch, and that will trigger the update of your website, from that branch.

Comment: @joanis I don't see any site or any link to my site.

Comment: You have to set things up completely first. You won't see any link until then. Choose Deploy from a branch, then pick which branch, and then Save. According to https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart about 10 minutes later, you should see your site live.